# Slideshow transition - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I'm trying to do a slideshow gallery in Javascript, but it doesn't work... When I run this code, the `src` goes to `veyron.jpg` instantly, skipping the `lamborghini.jpg`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="img" src="ferrari.jpg" />
    <script>
        img = document.getElementById("img");
        images = new Array("ferrari.jpg","lamborghini.jpg","veyron.jpg");
        end = images.length -1;

        window.onload = setInterval(slide,1000);        
        function slide(){
            for(i=0;i<=end;i++){
                img.src = images[i];
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why loop is exist here, you are casting all the images in all.

Do it with increment variable with `start`

```
 <script>
            var img = document.getElementById("img");
            var images = new Array("ferrari.jpg","lamborghini.jpg","veyron.jpg");
            var end = images.length -1;
            var start = 0;
            window.onload = setInterval(slide,1000);        
            function slide(){
               img.src = images[start%end];
               start++;
            }
 </script>
```

[example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbdcx6t2/)

Comment: Got it! i appreciate your support Ozgur!